# Rust multithreading slower with unsafe and no ownership

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, unsafe, ownership

In the original question, I was comparing the performance of two multithreaded solutions to summing over an array, called `with_to_owned` and `with_unsafe` below, and the question was why the to_owned version was faster than the unsafe version. That was performed using `std::time::{Duration, Instant}` in dev mode.

Below is the more accurate benchmarking code:

```
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::mem;
use std::thread;

#[inline]
fn baseline(v: &[i64], _n_threads: usize) -> i64 {
    v.iter().sum()
}

#[inline]
fn with_rayon(v: &[i64], _n_threads: usize) -> i64 {
    v.par_iter().sum()
}

#[inline]
fn with_to_owned(v: &[i64], n_threads: usize) -> i64 {
    let chunk_size = v.len() / n_threads;
    v.chunks(chunk_size)
        .map(|ch| ch.to_owned())
        .map(|ch| thread::spawn(move || ch.into_iter().sum::<i64>()))
        .map(|h| h.join().unwrap())
        .sum()
}

#[inline]
fn with_unsafe<'a>(v: &'a [i64], n_threads: usize) -> i64 {
    let chunk_size = v.len() / n_threads;
    unsafe { mem::transmute::<&'a [i64], &'static [i64]>(&v) }
        .chunks(chunk_size)
        .map(|ch| thread::spawn(move || ch.into_iter().sum::<i64>()))
        .map(|h| h.join().unwrap())
        .sum()
}

fn get_init_vector(n: usize) -> Vec<i64> {
    (0..n).map(|_| (0..1000)).flat_map(|x| x).collect()
}

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let v = get_init_vector(100000);
    let n_threads = 4usize;

    c.bench_function("baseline", |b| {
        b.iter(|| baseline(black_box(&v), black_box(n_threads)))
    });
    c.bench_function("rayon", |b| {
        b.iter(|| with_rayon(black_box(&v), black_box(n_threads)))
    });
    c.bench_function("to_owned", |b| {
        b.iter(|| with_to_owned(black_box(&v), black_box(n_threads)))
    });
    c.bench_function("unsafe", |b| {
        b.iter(|| with_unsafe(black_box(&v), black_box(n_threads)))
    });
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

And these are the results that I found:
For `n_threads = 3`

```
baseline                time:   [51.753 ms 55.417 ms 59.950 ms]                     
                        change: [+11.655% +19.194% +28.751%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 8 outliers among 100 measurements (8.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high mild
  7 (7.00%) high severe

rayon                   time:   [25.423 ms 26.522 ms 27.812 ms]                  
                        change: [+1.9189% +7.7540% +14.298%] (p = 0.01 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 9 outliers among 100 measurements (9.00%)
  5 (5.00%) high mild
  4 (4.00%) high severe

Benchmarking to_owned: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 64.4s, or reduce sample count to 10.
to_owned                time:   [581.78 ms 590.38 ms 599.46 ms]                     
                        change: [+128.89% +135.65% +142.14%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 8 outliers among 100 measurements (8.00%)
  7 (7.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe

Benchmarking unsafe: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 5.2s, or reduce sample count to 90.
unsafe                  time:   [54.789 ms 57.101 ms 59.650 ms]                   
                        change: [-0.3740% +5.5857% +12.336%] (p = 0.07 > 0.05)
                        No change in performance detected.
Found 11 outliers among 100 measurements (11.00%)
  8 (8.00%) high mild
  3 (3.00%) high severe
```

And for `n_threads = 8`:

```
baseline                time:   [46.113 ms 46.493 ms 46.905 ms]                     
                        change: [+908.91% +920.03% +932.32%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 9 outliers among 100 measurements (9.00%)
  6 (6.00%) high mild
  3 (3.00%) high severe

rayon                   time:   [23.891 ms 24.613 ms 25.501 ms]                  
                        change: [+897.88% +932.50% +968.32%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 13 outliers among 100 measurements (13.00%)
  5 (5.00%) high mild
  8 (8.00%) high severe

Benchmarking to_owned: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 23.4s, or reduce sample count to 20.
to_owned                time:   [244.74 ms 250.54 ms 256.78 ms]                     
                        change: [+966.26% +1000.8% +1036.7%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 4 outliers among 100 measurements (4.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe

Benchmarking unsafe: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Warning: Unable to complete 100 samples in 5.0s. You may wish to increase target time to 5.3s, or reduce sample count to 90.
unsafe                  time:   [52.033 ms 54.080 ms 56.389 ms]                   
                        change: [+777.17% +818.74% +867.32%] (p = 0.00 < 0.05)
                        Performance has regressed.
Found 13 outliers among 100 measurements (13.00%)
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  9 (9.00%) high severe
```

So it seems like the to_owned vs not to_owned question is moot. But, this brings up two more things that I'm curious about:

1. Why is the benchmark result so different? What types of optimizations are likely occurring that make the unsafe version faster, and why didn't they occur when just running in dev mode?
2. How is Rayon so fast? This is the simplest threading code I could think of, what do they do to get better performance?

Comment: Yes, of course! But would it be reasonable to think that the margin of error is outside the bounds of benchmarking error? For what it's worth, Rayon runs perfectly fine here, and gives about 3x speed over the baseline. I just didn't include that part to make things tighter.

Comment: Iterators are "lazy", so the loop is essentially doing `for ...  { .spawn(...).join() }` which is sequential execution with added overhead of spawning threads.

Comment: Also your ratio is reversed: you divide `diff_own` by `diff_unsafe` which is = how many times slower `to_owned` is.

Comment: You don't need `unsafe`, you can use scoped threads, they were just stabilized.

Comment: For two questions please open two SO questions (although I don't think you'll get an answer here for the first question, the answer is pretty much "everything").

Comment: Yeah the ratio thing was just a copy edit, the original code was actually quite different and looked closer to the current one that is there now. I updated everything per the suggestions! I guess I don't have a good intuition on the ordering of how iterators are applied. If I apply a.ops1().ops2(), I would expect that all operations in ops1 are applied before ops2 i.e. (ops1_1, ops1_2) > (ops2_1, ops2_2). Which, in this case, would mean all threads are spawned first, and only then joined. Are you saying it's possible to have (ops1_1, ops2_1), (ops1_2, ops2_2)?

Comment: I suspect Rayon reuses threads instead of spawning them every time

Comment: Rayon uses work stealing, and I think that's why it's faster (the spawning itself should not be so significant).